# Numerical Methods - Relative Error

Tags: numerical-methods, truncation-error

In our lectures, we've been looking at relative error and in our recent problem sheet we were asked to prove the following:

Let $\hat{x} \neq 0$ be an approximation of a non-zero quantity $x$. Consider the relative error $ e = \frac{|x- \hat{x}|}{|x|}$ and the error normalised using the approximation $\hat{x}$, $\hat{e} = \frac{|x-\hat{x}|}{|\hat{x}|}$.

Assuming that $\hat{e} < 1$, show that there exist quantities $f_1(\hat{e})$ and $f_2(\hat{e})$ such that $f_1(\hat{e}) ≤ e ≤ f_2(\hat{e})$.

I'm honestly not sure where to begin with this, especially since $f_1$ and $f_2$ are functions of $\hat{e}$. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Please do not delete questions after receiving an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to write you an answer, and to those who might be helped by that answer in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$e = \frac{|x-\hat{x}|}{|x|} = \frac{|x-\hat{x}|}{|\hat{x}|}\frac{|\hat{x}|}{|x|} \leq \hat{e}\left(1 + \frac{|\hat{x}-x|}{|x|}\right) = \hat{e}(1+e).$$
This implies $e(1-\hat{e}) \leq \hat{e}$ and therefore $e \leq \frac{\hat{e}}{1-\hat{e}}$ assuming $\hat{e} < 1$.

Can you show the other inequality now?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm confused on how you got the inequality though. Could you please explain?

Comment: That's just the triangle inequality, $|\hat{x}| \leq |x| + |\hat{x}-x|$.

Comment: Ah, I see! I'm still having trouble with the other side of the inequality, however. Could you please show me how you would do that as well? Thank you!

Comment: @user839136 You just use the reverse triangle inequality instead: $|\hat{x}| \geq |x| - |x-\hat{x}|$.